# How do I open the iron gate under the Precipice of Recompense?

Tags: doom-eternal

In the second part of the second level (Hell), underneath the "Precipice of Recompense" spawn point, there is a wrought iron gate next to a blue jet jumper. I reached the end of the level but am unable to open this gate—how does it open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a path that leads behind the fence on the right. You'll have to swing on a bar to get there. It's in ground level